# Generalised circles in the context of Moebius transformations

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, linear-fractional-transformation

I‘m doing complex analysis at the moment and while speaking about Möbius transformations we introduced the notion of a generalized circle. It seems to be a really important construct while discussing Möbius transformations since this transformations have good properties w.r.t. generalized circles. But somehow I don‘t know how to think about this generalized circles since our Prof. told us they are not circles as in the usual way.

Could  maybe someone take some time and explain me how to think about this and also maybe how I get an intuition?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What book are you using?

Comment: @Aplateofmomos we use „Complex analysis“ from Donald Marshall

Comment: How are you define generalised circle?

Comment: @Aplateofmomos In this book they wrote a generalised circle is a circle or a straight line. But in class the prof said that it is a „circle“ or a straight line where a „circle“ is not equal to a usual circle is‘t much more general

Comment: Ok I understand.

Comment: @Aplateofmomos sorry I edited ma last post again.

Comment: So do you think you can help me?

Comment: Did my answer help you? if not , let me know

Comment: I would suggest you [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0z1fIsUNhO4) . I found it a beautiful presentation of Moebius transformations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A mobius transformation can be dissected into the following four transformations done successively:

1. Translation
2. Inversion $ \frac{1}{z}$ map
3. Expansion and rotation
4. Another translation

Details in page-124 of Tristan Needham's VCA.

Now,  it is pretty clear that step 1.,3.,4. would preserve circle. The only thing in doubt is step 2. . Let us study it in detail.

We can think step-2 as a two-step process:

$$  z \to \frac{1}{\overline{z}} \to \frac{1}{z}$$

Now clearly reflection preserves circles (second step here), so the study boils down first transformation. The first step turns out to be a geometrically rich transformation known as geometric inversion, in particular, we have a geometric inversion over the unit circle. Note that whenever we talk about geometric inversion, we always do it across a circle.

Geometrically speaking, if we were to map the whole plane to a Riemann sphere, the geometric inversion step would just be reflecting the Riemann sphere across the complex plane. Note that the Riemann sphere I am talking about sits like this:

> [image]
>
> Page-141 , VCA

We can find show that Geometric inversion has the follow properties:

1. If a line $L$ does not pass through the center of the circle of inversion, then inversion maps it to a circle that passes through center. Note that inversion is a self inverse transformation, so it occurs the opposite way too (circle through center-> line not through center). (pg-127)
2. If a circle $C$ does not pass through center of circle of inversion, then inversion maps it another circle not passing through center of circle of inversion.

Furthermore we can see that inversion essentially behaves like reflection along lines as we increase the radius of the circle we are inverting over( Page-130). Here is a gif of how it happens ([graph link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator)):

[image]

Due to all of this , it would be reasonable here to call a 'line' as a 'circle' as well in the context of mobius transformation.

Comment: Wow perfect thanks! So but then we really can think of a circle or a line geometrically when speaking about generalised circles

Comment: I have edited the answer a bit. Let me know if it helps. I don't really understand your comment there, could you say it in another way?

Comment: Ah I see now why we really can say it is a circle respectivly a line. Since we have a diffenrence between a circle passing through the center of circle of inversion and one who do not pass through this center. If it passes then the inversion is again a circle otherwise it is a line. Is it because of that why we speak about generalised circles?

Comment: Not just that, as I show above, we can see a line as circle whose center is far away and radius is very large. And, if you do reflection across it , it would be like doing inversion across this gigantic circle. So due to all these similarities, it makes sense to call it as soon @Wave

Comment: Ah okey thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help you!