# Find a möbius transformation from the line to the unit circle?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, mobius-transformation

> Let us take the line $\gamma=\{1+\lambda i:\lambda\in \Bbb{R}\}$ I want to find a möbius transformation to the unit circle.

My idea was to map $1\mapsto 1$, $\frac{1}{2}\mapsto 0$ and $\frac{3}{2}\mapsto \infty$. Solving a small system of linear equalities I would get that $$f(z)=\frac{-4z+2}{4z-6}=\frac{-2z+1}{2z-3}$$

Is this correct so?

Comment: Is there any particular reason for this choice of mappings? They don’t seem relevant to the original locus or the intended image.

Comment: @DavidQuinn sorry what do you mean?

Comment: Why for example would you want to map $\frac32$ to $\infty$?

Comment: @DavidQuinn so that the möbius transformation respects symmetrie.

Comment: I wonder why you chose $1$, $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{3}{2}$ in the domain of your map? The points $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{3}{2}$ lie neither on the line $\gamma$ nor on the unit circle.

Comment: I agree.  I would try something like $1 \mapsto 1, 1+i\mapsto i, 1-i \mapsto -i, \infty\mapsto -1$

Comment: @LeeMosher I thought that this points are symmetric with respect to the line and then their images also needs to be symmetric with respect to the unit circle?

Comment: I guess it makes sense. Suppose we have the mobius transformation $M(z)$ and we compose that with reflection aong the line $\gamma$ as $R_{\gamma}$, then we have $ M \circ R_{\gamma}(z)$. Now the thing is that suppose we plug the line $\gamma$ to this, we should still get the same out put as passing into $M(z)$ as the reflection keeps the point on line invariant

Comment: What would make much more sense is something like in the comment of @GEdgar: choose three points on the line $\gamma$ and map them to three chosen points on the unit circle.

Comment: Hi @Wave I made an error in my post. I mistook the geometric inversion as a moebius transformation. It is actually not, but once you compose it with the reflection it is. Hope this helps.

Comment: Strictly speaking, we need to take $\gamma \cup \{ \infty \}$, but your solution is correct. The points $f(1/2) = 0$ and $f(3/2) = \infty$ are symmetric (conjugate) wrt $f(\gamma)$, so $f(\gamma)$ is a circle centered at the origin. $f(1) = 1$ fixes the circle. The general form of the desired Mobius transformation is $e^{i \phi} (z - z_0)/(z - 2 + \overline {z_0})$ with $z_0 \not \in \gamma$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most intuitive way to do this is to use [inversion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4462145/688539)!

> If a line $L$ does not pass through the center of the circle of inversion, then inversion maps it to a circle that passes through center. Note that inversion is a self inverse transformation, so it occurs the opposite way too (circle through center-> line not through center). (pg-127)

To get the line to a circle centered at origin, all we have to do is invert it by the unit circle centered at origin and then reflect along x axis

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$$

We can now check that this transformation sends the line to a circle at center $.5$ with radius $.5$, by a sequence of a translation, by shifting and dilating, we find the final transformation as:

$$ T(z) =  2( \frac{1}{z} - .5)$$

**Note: There is no unique moebius transformation here, your equation is correct too! One can compose the final eqtn I got with a further maps which preserve the unit circle to get other moebius transformations doing the same.**

Comment: $T(z) =  2( \frac{1}{\overline{z}} - .5)$ is *not* a Möbius transformation, and not even an analytic function.

Comment: Mistake fixed it now. Thanks for letting me know @MartinR

Comment: It is also possible to adapt the rational parametrisation of the circle: $z = -\frac{t - i}{t + i}$ where $t$ is real.